# Safe to image disk from host OS (Windows 10) while it is running?

Tags: windows-10, disk-image, macrium

I need to create a disk image of a non-virtualized Windows 10 GPT partition (C drive) using Macrium Reflect.

**Is it better/safer/more reliable to image the disk from USB boot media (WinPE or WinRE) than from Windows while it is running?** I've searched Macrium's site and couldn't find anything regarding the differences or trade-offs.

If I do create the image from Windows while it is running, is there anything I should be concerned about  like the virus scanner, Volume Shadow Service, Windows Updates, ... (I think by default Macrium skips the pagefile)?

I'm also not sure if there are any steps needed to take if the drive is BitLocker enabled (which I think it is).

Comment: Been using MRF for years, always image it while in windows, never had any issues doing this.

Comment: Macrium reported a successful backup and validation, however the destination drive (D, USB ATAPI bridge-connected IDE) was pegged at 100% (in task manager) after closing out Macrium. I couldn't manually eject drive so attempted a reboot which resulted in a blue screen followed by a failed OS load and then into a Recovery prompt (probably attempted to boot to D, need to check BIOS, but still not very smooth).

Comment: I've not used MRF - but as a general rule, it is safer to work on an unmounted disk or disk snapshot as it removes the risk of filesystem inconsistency. In reality this risk is not massive due to file journalling.

Comment: Opening Disk Management after closing Macrium seemed to cause the external USB drive to lock at 100%. Task Manager reported USB disk to drop to 0% immediately upon image completion. Closing Macrium also didn't cause any further disk activity. Then, Opening Disk Management, which hung with a blank screen during loading, caused the external drive's activity to jump and stay at 100%. [Windows 10 - Task Manager Reports 100% Disk Utilization with MSI Mode Enabled](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-ca/sln298828/windows-10-task-manager-reports-100-disk-utilization-with-msi-mode-enabled?lang=en)

Answer (score 3):

I use this software all the time and have not noticed any difference between a clone within windows vs. a clone within a USB bootable environment apart from speed. This is cancelled out by the time it takes to build the USB bootable image and booting up the computer from it.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to image a disk while Windows is running. Why would Macrium create a program that was not safe to use? Normally no special precautions are needed.

The main advantage of using the Windows version is convenience. That is the only way I have made an image with Macrium Reflect and there have been no problems.

The WinPE version would be needed when restoring the image to a new drive. It can be used to create an image of a computer that does not have Macrium Reflect installed. Or it could be used when Windows will not run. You could create the image and they proceed with repair or recovery procedures.

Comment: Well I have recently made a bootable WinRE (or PE) Macrium USB drive and imaged from there but as you stated it's not very convenient and runs rather slowly. However, now that I'll be doing regular backups that I'll be counting on I wanted to make sure they were reliable is all.

Comment: Reflect on a USB with WinRE works nicely even on a pure Linux system. Only disadvantage: Linux must be unmounted, because it does not have Windows' Volume Shadow Copy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Macrium specifically, but the live imaging software suits use more or less the same "technology" to do the live image.

You can create the image both ways, in most cases, the software will make sure that your data is consistent. Simply speaking this will be the case for standard software (specifically all Windows features) but there might be problems for non-standard software. The worst-case scenario would be that the snapshot would be the "disk state" after a "cold reset". Depending on what is running while you take the image you need to take this into consideration. This is the reason why you should always test the recovery after the backup.

Live images are mostly used for systems that can not be shut down to create the image. If you have the option and want to avoid risks, especially if you don't have the time or the know-how how to test thoroughly I would advise you to do a shut down before the image will be taken.

Depending on how Bitlocker is set up, you might need to store the decryption key separately. Again "testing is king".